# why eclipse plugin cannot find google speech library class on Runtime?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

I am trying to develop an eclipse plugin which converts speech to text. I am using google speech API. On compile I have no problem, however, I faced an exception on Runtime which says :

```
com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechClient cannot be found by org.plugin.helper_1.0.0.qualifier
```

I am wondering what is the problem?

[image: Plugin structure]

[image: imported libraries]

[image: Runtime Exception]

Update :

Here is my MANIFEST.MF and run configuration :

[image: manifest]

[image]

Comment: Plugins only look for classes in their dependencies listed in the MANIFEST.MF and jars included in the plugin. They do **not** look at the Java build path. It is not clear what you are doing here.

Comment: Show your `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file and the run configuration tab _Plug-ins_ (to know how the dependency is specified and included)?

Comment: Please show your full error message as text (are there more _Caused by: ..._?). Maybe `com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechClient` needs something that is missing in your target platform.

Comment: You only have on Google plug-in in the dependencies - does that contain the speech classes? If not where are they?